# How to adjust column width whilst maintaining centered text for table

Tags: tables

How do I make the column width the same whilst keeping the text centered for the following table?

```
   \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{BET specific surface areas of each of the silicas used in this work, as calculated by \cite{}.}
\label{specificarea}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Silicas     & Specific surface area, S [\si{\m \tothe{2} \per \gram}] \\ \midrule
CARiACT Q3  & 438.0                                                   \\
CARiACT Q6  & 359.0                                                   \\
CARiACT Q10 & 303.0                                                   \\
CARiACT Q15 & 196.0                                                   \\
CARiACT Q30 & 112.0                                                   \\
CARiACT Q50 & 71.0                                                    \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
```

I have tried using

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5cm}p{5cm}@{}}
```

But the text is not centered anymore.

Comment: Use: `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}@{}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a reasonably recent `array` package, then you can set the width using `w`, replace  `c` by `wc{2cm}`

Answer (score 4):

Another way that maintain the decimal align:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=8.8]S[table-format=9.7]}
\toprule
{Silicas}     & {\parbox{9em}{\centering Specific surface area\\ S [\si{\m \tothe{2} \per \gram}]}} \\ \midrule
{CARiACT Q3}  & 438.0                                                   \\
{CARiACT Q6}  & 359.0                                                   \\
{CARiACT Q10} & 303.0                                                   \\
{CARiACT Q15} & 196.0                                                   \\
{CARiACT Q30} & 112.0                                                   \\
{CARiACT Q50} & 71.0                                                    \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes the OP should accept this really, I wondered about mentioning that centred columns wouldn't look good here, but I decided to answer the question as asked...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Anyway you answer is very helpful (+1) because `w` columns are still a *rara avis* in the tons of examples of LaTeX tables out there, and people not always will need a decimal align.